# android apps login data is not passing from my app to my php file

Tags: java, php, android

```
class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private EditText user, pass;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://ridgepvt.com/android/loginapp.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button bLogin;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                String username1 = user.getText().toString();
                String password1 = pass.getText().toString();
                new AttemptLogin(username1,password1).execute();

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        boolean failure = false;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        public AttemptLogin(String username1, String password1) {
            super();
            username = username;
            password = password;
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;


            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1)
                { Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
                    Intent ii = new Intent(Login.this,OtherActivity.class);

                    startActivity(ii);
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String message)
        { pDialog.dismiss();
            if (message != null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR IS LOGICAL ITS NOT PASSING MY STRING DATA TO PHP FILE. THE ERROR WAS COMING WHEN I WAS USING GET.TEXT function in background but i tried to solve it by overriding the constructor and passing the data as parameter in the OnClick function

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you are using

```
 public AttemptLogin(String username1, String password1) {
        super();
        username = username;
        password = password;
    }
```

instead use

```
 public AttemptLogin(String username1, String password1) {
        super();
        username = username1;
        password = password1;
    }
```

Comment: put log value of username and password in the doInBackground method